# SharePoint 2010 no code deployment

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, deployment, staging

Is it possible to deploy changes from a Staging environment to production environment without custom code or solution packages?

Basically, I don't want to disturb an existing content. Suppose in dev server I have added a XSLT webpart to a site say through SP Designer and customized that.

How can I take it from the staging server to production via PowerShell? I mean how can I replicate (without disturbing content) same customization to OOB content through powershell command in SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 1):

Wow.  I am surprised someone would say that.  My problem has been that there are so many ways of doing custom development for SharePoint 2010.  Choosing-the-best-one/where-to-start has been my biggest challenge(s).  The four that I have tried (and seen the most) are:

1. Customizing the SharePoint templates (to create a different look/feel)
2. Web Parts (.net)
3. ASP.NET pages and Web Services that can be hosted within SharePoint
4. ASP.NET pages and Web Services that are hosted beside SharePoint but seem integrated

Each of these are deployed in one of three ways:

- 1 and 3 are deployed directly into SharePoint (upload, or UNC copy) - Either there is no code or the code is embedded in the page
- 2 must be installed into the server (by a server admin) then activated via SP Admin and then added to a page.  Visual Studio 2010 also has a quick (automated) way of doing this for you. - The code is compiled into a DLL which has to be inserted into the GAC.
- 4 can be added to the HDD of your SharePoint servers. (usually c:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss* or some other similar folder.  - The code is compiled into a DLL and sits in the bin folder of the project (outside of SharePoint).

The docs on MSDN are all really lengthy because this topic is so broad.  If you narrow-down your architecture to one of these, it helps reduce your search results.  Otherwise, if you want to consider all options, this MSDN article covers the topic pretty thoroughly: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff829215.aspx

Comment: this is not proper answer to this question. Any one else plz give the proper answer for this.

Comment: I think item number 1 relates mostly to your question but its really to tell what's being asked. You might want to make an attempt at clarifying your question to get answers you find more suited to your question.

Comment: Could you identify why this is not a proper answer?  It might help me (or others) determine a better answer.

Comment: Gosh, your updated question is so much different from your original question. You still need to deploy the web part (option 2). Then you could use the SharePoint designer to copy/paste the content. I don't know of any powershell scripts that can backup/restore one page and one web part. It might be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Basically,  I don't want to disturb an existing content. Suppose in dev server I have added a XSLT webpart to a site say through SP Designer and customized that. How can I take it to the staging server through powershell command? I mean how can I replicate (without disturbing content) same customization to OOB content through powershell command in SharePoint 2010?

Comment: You should not post updates in the answers section, please update your original posts when you have new information to add.